# Does the principle of Hadash Asur Min Hatorah apply to technological new things?

Tags: halacha, technology, acharonim

According to the Hatam Sofer, does this principle apply to technological novelties? This principle means that "New Is Forbidden By The Torah".

Answer (score 11):

Certainly not.

Hatam Sofer was opposed to certain innovations and changes that were being proposed for Judaism in his time and place. He responded with a catchy phrase -- "the Torah prohibits the new", which is a play on words -- the Torah prohibits the new year's grain crop *until the second day of Passover*.

If you study his responsa in more detail, a far more nuanced view becomes clear. For instance: the prevailing custom had been (in his world) to write only the Hebrew date on a tombstone, and suddenly many people wanted the secular (i.e. Gregorian) date on there as well. He fiercely resisted this change. Yet we have documents/letters where he used the Gregorian date. It's not that the new calendar was inherently forbidden in any way shape or form --  it was the sudden, dangerous changes to longstanding Jewish practice.

Similarly, in responsum OC159 ([see this great blog for more](http://bdld.info/2010/07/01/clean-shaven-kabbalists-crusades-and-censorship/)) he sharply defended Jewish men who were clean-shaven, so long as they didn't use a razor. *"But Jewish men used to always have beards!"*, they protested. *"Guess what? All the pagan men in Biblical times did too!"*, he replied.

Hatam Sofer did not live to see the innovation of the matza-baking machine, but many wonder how he would have felt about it -- as some changes he felt were safe, some were dangerous. His ghost is felt in the responsa about it -- his son the Ktav Sofer allows the machines, and concludes, "G-d forbid my father's offspring would allow something prohibited."

Comment: He was one of those who approved doing Metziza with a sponge. http://onthemainline.blogspot.co.il/2012/04/chasam-sofers-ruling-on-metzitzah-be.html

Comment: He also uses this phrase to refer to new forms of Torah learning, in his haskama to the Kesef Nivchar